# Endless iteration on Scala mutable ArrayBuffer

Tags: scala

I can loop infinitely on a mutable ArrayBuffer in Scala 2.10.4:

```
scala> import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

scala> val a = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
a: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

scala> val b = a.iterator
b: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator

scala> b.take(50).toList
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

scala> b.hasNext
res1: Boolean = true
```

Is there something I'm not understanding correctly?  I can do the same with a List and it works well.  It is as if the take(nn).toList does not advance the iterator on an ArrayBuffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is something you are missing. The contract of the `take` method on an `Iterator` indicates that it is unsafe to use the iterator after that method is invoked. Please read the API documentation:

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.0/index.html#scala.collection.Iterator

The `take` method documentation states:

> Reuse: After calling this method, one should discard the iterator it was called on, and use only the iterator that was returned. Using the old iterator is undefined, subject to change, and may result in changes to the new iterator as well.

So, using an extra variable to capture the result of `take` yields what you expected:

```
scala> import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

scala> val a = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
a: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

scala> val b = a.iterator
b: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator

scala> val c = b.take(50)
c: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator

scala> c.toList
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

scala> c.hasNext
res1: Boolean = false
```

Comment: Yeah, I don't particularly like the design myself but it is what it is.

Comment: What would be the right way to do this in a loop?  It seems that reassigning the result of the take on a 'var' does not work as intended either.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "this"? :) Are you just looking for `a.grouped(50)` by some chance?

Comment: Yes.. seems so..  Looks like I need to re-read the API and the countless of methods a collection has!